# Modifying a SVG path to create word art like effects

Tags: graphics, svg, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I am trying to modify a SVG file which has a path converted from a text. I want to be able to manipulate it to create Word Art like effects (eg: Wedge, Widen, Curved text etc).

I've tried many options like parsing the file and modifying each point, but the results are bizarre and curves go wild. There is no tool/library to do this kinda stuff to an svg file.

In short, I am looking for a tool like ImageMagick but for svg. Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) can do some of this I think, also see this [writeup by Tavmjong Bah](http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/TEXT_PATH/TextPath.html). Inkscape uses a library called [lib2geom](http://lib2geom.sourceforge.net/) to do these effects, and there seems to be a [python wrapper](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Lib2geom_py2geom) for that library.